# Reading all the leaf nodes for a given Parent Node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I need a list of leaf nodes under the given parent  node body.
Basically I want all the nodes like
11 and 10
from the below XML.

I tried this but it brings all the nodes.
//*[not(*)]

for example I want to give something like this
 var vNode= nodeBody.SelectNodes("Body"+@"//*[not(*)]");

which should get be all the leaf nodes under Body.

```
    <MAIN Txt="PC">
      <BODY Txt="TC">
        <Element_3 Txt="OC">
          <Element3_ID Name="yoy">10</Element3_ID>
        </Element_3>
        <Element_3 Txt="TRO">
          <Element_4 Txt="SSO">
            <Element4_ID Name="JOY">11</Element4_ID>
            <Element4_ID Name="TOY">13</Element4_ID>
            <Element4_ID Name="POY">14</Element4_ID>
            <Element4_ID Name="SOY">17</Element4_ID>
            <Element4_ID Name="GOY">18</Element4_ID>
            <Element4_ID Name="FOY">19</Element4_ID>
          </Element_4>
        </Element_3>
      </BODY>
    </MAIN>
```

Comment: I see you have added a `c#` tag... is there any reason why you can't use `Linq2XML` in C# instead of xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the path `.//node()[not(node())]` to select all descendant nodes not having any child nodes which would give you any empty element nodes and all text nodes or use `.//*[not(*)]` to select all descendant element nodes not containing any other element nodes. If you don't want to select completely empty element nodes then use `.//*[not(*) and normalize-space()]`.